# Sorting Data from Firestore and display on Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

```
let currentUserEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
db.collection("vmList")
    .whereField("vmUserEmail", isEqualTo: "\(currentUserEmail!)")
    .order(by: "title", descending: false)
    .getDocuments { (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
           print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
           self.videoInfos = (querySnapshot?.documents)!
           self.listTable.reloadData()  
        }
     }
```

I am trying to sort nodes from Firestore to display on Tableview. When the tableview is loaded, the activity indictor just keeps spinning and shows the error messages below. So I added index (see below), but still have the same errors.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E20ig.png)

The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/xxxxxx-63d67/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cklwcm9qZWN0cy9kZHZtLTYzZDY3L2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy92bUxpc3QvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaDwoLdm1Vc2VyRW1haWwQARoJCgV0aXRsZRABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE

2020-02-25 22:28:37.122904-0600 DDVM[66799:4345889] 6.17.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at vmList failed: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/xxxxxx-63d67/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cklwcm9qZWN0cy9kZHZtLTYzZDY3L2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy92bUxpc3QvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaDwoLdm1Vc2VyRW1haWwQARoJCgV0aXRsZRABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE

Answer (score 0):

It may take quite some time for the index to be created. Until that is done, there is no chance of the query working.

If the index creation lasts longer than say 30 minutes or so, check the JavaScript console for any relevant errors. If that doesn't show anything, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.